# Regular expression to select templatized words

Tags: regex

I want to find all the words enclosed within a `{}` using a regular expression.

If my string is `'The Insured Addr {Address} is not valid for {Name}'`,

I want to pull out only `'Address'` and `'Name'` . I have been trying for couple of hours without success.

Any help is really appreciated.

I tried `([/{]([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)[}])`

This does not work.

I am using C#. Also the templates can contain dot notated properties as in 'Address.city','ABC.PQR.XYZ'

Comment: Yogendra, I assume the inner text of these `{...}` tags *can't* contain the characters `{` and `}`, right?

Comment: Yes Bart, they cannot contain those characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{(?<name>\w+)}
```

This will capture the text within the `{` and `}` within a group named `name`.

In C#:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"{(?<name>.+?)}");
MatchCollection coll = r.Matches("The Insured Addr {Address} is not valid for {Name}");
foreach (Match m in coll) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"]);
}
```

Prints

```
Address
Name
```

on the console.

Comment: that solves the issue. It will not work if I have Name.FirstName or something like Address.City.Zip

Answer (score 2):

```
/{(.+?)}/
```

This will get anything inside of braces, even multiple words.

If you expect that you might have whitespace padding, you could use:

```
/{\s*([\S+]+?)\s*}/
```

This will mean that {Address} and {   Address } return the same thing.  In this version, no other spaces are allowed in the tag, but you could just as easily do (.+?).   The ? means that it will find a word within the two closest braces.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\{([a-z0-9]+)\}/i
```

I don't know what language you are using, but the word inside braces will be captured into the first submatch group.

For instance, using Ruby:

```
str = 'The Insured Addr {Address} is not valid for {Name}'
matches = str.scan(/\{([a-z0-9]+)\}/i).flatten
# => ['Address', 'Name']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'The Insured Addr {Address} is not valid for {Name}'
>>> re.findall('\{([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\}', s)
['Address', 'Name']
```

Comment: Probably a typo: `[a-zA-z]` should probably be `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 1):

The regex:

```
\{([^}]*)}
```

will match both `'{Address}'` and `'{Name}'` and will capture `'Address'` and `'Name'` in match group 1. Because `[^}]` also matches line breaks, it will also work if `{` and `}` are on a different line (which is not the case with `.*?`).

Answer (score 0):

`\{(.*?)\}`

The `*?` instead of `*` is for lazyness, to not catch `{Address} is not valid for {Name}` as one long unit. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) under "Laziness Instead of Greediness".

Comment: Since `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` does not match `}`, there is no need for laziness.

Answer (score 0):

{([^}]*)}  Will grab the first one.